# What is the best way to kill the Siren on Hard in Bioshock Infinite?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I have been having a really hard time beating the 3 tears of Lady Comstock, I have been trying to kill her and her army of the undead with the shotgun, carbine, and a repeater/machine gun I pick from the corpses along with the Return To Sender, Charge, and Bucking Bronco.

Needless to say, even with my best efforts, I have been very unsuccessful in beating her after 2 hours of being stuck in a single tear, The Bank of the Prophet. Any tactics would be highly appreciated, since I have since gotten frustrated and finished the game in easy.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The easiest way is to use any gun and keep shooting at her and run straight into the oppsite staircase and hide behind the columns. Kill the coming soldiers easily ( probably 5 soldiers ) she is only left then kill her

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had less trouble than I was expecting with these fights, even on 1999 Mode.  I [covered it](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/posts/2096) in my 1999 guide, but I'll summarize here.

Lady Comstock takes critical hit damage from being hit almost anywhere, so critical hit boosting gear is very nice.

The Charge vigor, upgraded with the invulnerability option, makes this fight much easier.  If you have Brittle Skinned as a gear option, the fight is downright trivial.  Throw in a fully upgraded shotgun and the whole thing is over before she can summon her second set of goons.

1. Hit her with whatever ranged weapons you have - I tended to bring a crank gun.
2. When your shields are low, Charge her, which causes you to melee.   This will activate invulnerability, plus recharge your shields.  This also pops the Brittle Skinned bonus if you've got it.
3. Unload your shotgun, and then fire off whatever else you can until your shields are down.

Once your invulnerability wears off and your shields are low, just Charge again.  You could also retreat once the shotgun is empty, and reload your weapons and prepare to start from the beginning if that suits your playstyle better.

On 1999 mode, with around 5 infusion points into salts, I was able to take her down before I'd even halfway drained my salts or shotgun ammo.

The Charge upgrade can be somewhat expensive if you haven't saved your cash or prioritized it, but I didn't get it until just before this fight, and I just scrounged around the city, looking for enough change to afford it.  There's a lot of ground you can cover in this area looking for resources.

You can use Vigors or set Vigor traps if you're having issues with her minions - Shock Jockey is pretty good for this.  If you upgrade Charge with the explosive damage upgrade, you'll probably do pretty decent damage to them when you Charge anyhow.  Bronco is my go-to crowd control option if things are getting hairy in close.  When they're stunned, I believe they take additional damage, so if you've got a bunch of them on you, it might be useful to stun them to avoid wasting ammo.

You must fight her three times before she goes down, and I've listed the locations in my guide.  It helps to go in fully loaded, upgraded, and healed, so knowing where she will attack can make a big difference.

Answer (score 15):

If you kill any of her ghost soldiers normally, she can easily resurrect them. Kill them in such a way that they leave no corpse (Shock Jockey or Devil's Kiss). If you do this, her supply of soldiers will slowly dry up until only she is left. Upgrading the Shock Jockey to affect multiple enemies and using it in conjunction with Undertow will also speed things up significantly.

Weapon-wise, the Siren is very mobile so you don't want to rely on weapons that are accuracy-dependent (Sniper Rifle). The machine guns and shotguns are good options. And the volley gun's area-of-effect also make it a viable choice for dealing damage to both Lady Comstock and her minions at once, killing two birds with one stone.

Comment: I beat her in 1999 mode by hiding, pumping shotgun bullets into her and screaming like a girl.  But, I've heard that an upgraded "charge" attack while make you invincible for a short while, allowing you to kill her without getting hurt.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Yes, I can confirm that the upgraded charge technique is also a great one, since none of the other vigors work directly

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way I found is, before the fight, lay 10 fully upgraded Devil's Kiss traps at Siren's spawn location. It will take her out immediately even on 1999 mode.

- First fight - Before you open the crypt: on the stone road outside the crypt a few steps from the round intersection.
- Second fight - When you enter the Vault's main hall area for the first time (right after you left the elevator): on the floor next to the side of desks in the middle of the hall close to the vault door.
- Third fight - Before you open the last tear: on the floor next to Lady Comstock's statue on the side where the gate is.

The only drawback is the high demand on salts. Luckily the map has many salt bottles lying around. And thanks to the many skylines and hooks, it should be easy to conserve them using the "Winter Shield" trick.

Here is it in action:

Answer (score 2):

I defeated her on hard by, no matter how many times I died , focusing on eradicating her soldiers (killing them without leaving a corpse via shock jockey). When there were no more bodies for her to resurrect I found it much easier to just keep blasting her with a shotgun whilst keeping my distance during her attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I found `Return to Sender` to be quite efficient at taking down the Siren in hard.
With all the lackies she has, using the Vigor's shield to protect yourself from damage while shooting her with the MG or Repeater, then launching it all back towards the Siren from time to times, usually took about 1-3 minutes to take her down without any major loss in health or ammo.

Paired with the Gear that refunds Salts upon enemy deaths and the efficiency upgrade for the Vigor, the fight against the Siren doesn't drain too much Salts.

And with the absorption improvement, awarding some of the shielded shots to your ammo, it is also very useful in refilling your already scarce supplies.

Answer (score 1):

I just threw fire at her ads to keep em' busy, then sniped her till she pooped out. I never worried about killing the ads, just focused on her. I stood near dolla bill the whole fight and bought ammo and salts when needed. I dont understand how people run out of salts, ammo or health on this fight with a vendor with in sniping distance. I dont think I ever moved once in this fight, just kept shooting her in the face and launching fire bombs, except to run and buy salts and sniper bullets. Game pauses when buying at vendor. Easy peasy on normal mode. Took all of 3 minutes..Good luck!!
 BTW, my sniper rifle was upgraded to max and I was spec'ed out for most damage using it as well.

Comment: Thing is, it is harder in hard. I can assure you I attempted that for a long time and it had a negligible progress.

Comment: Did you upgrade sniper rifle and spec your gear for most damage with it?

Comment: No, I was using a shotgun, which was upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

I just killed her last night on hard. I primarily used a sniper rifle, which has been upgraded for max damage. I stood just outside the circular door, moving left and right for cover. When her ads rushed me, I retreated to force them away from her (outside the circular door) then killed them using a shorter range gun and my abilities.

Good luck!
Nemrok

Answer (score 0):

The boss fight is easy, with the right tools. The head master gear is a life saver and very useful, but not needed. The fights are actually very easy. You will need a weapon with a scope, preferrably a sniper or a burstgun. All you have to do is take cover and aim at an enemy for a while until the siren goes near it. Then kill the enemy and spam shots at the siren while she ressurects him. It may be tedious, but it won't be difficult

Answer (score 0):

This fight is actually pretty straight forward, although the first time I played the game I gave up after a handful or two of tries. You want to lay a trap whenever she summons, aiming it at about where she hovers.

The trap is of course your choice, but one which destroys bodies is preferable (shock or Fire). While she's raising the bodies she is incapable of stopping your actions and can be hit with spells, which will not only damage her but her freshly summoned minions as well.

To be honest, I think the weapon you hurt her with is totally of your own choice, be it a vigor combo, firearm (close range, or long range) or a well upgraded Sky-Hook. Personally I used a fully upgraded Burst-Gun, and a Vox-Repeater (also fully upgraded). Although I'm willing to bet a combination of "Return to Sender" with a RPG or Volley/Hail Fire would be equally as effective.

I think you'll find she'll die rather quickly if you have created a character capable of carrying their own, which I mean choosing your Phial uses wisely. Hope this helps anyone/everyone, and honestly don't be tricked into thinking you need to caary flashy weapons... I'm using the Vox Repeater and Burst Gun and demolishing the game, early on I used the combo of a lightly upgraded Machine Gun and barely upgraded Carbine. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

For the bank, just hide inside the vault.  Peek out, kill a minion, then blast her while she is resurrecting him.  Hide when your shield goes down.  They will not go into the vault.  If you run out of ammo or salts, and for some reason Elizabeth is being stingy with handing them out, make a mad dash to the Vending machine in the far corner, going through the offices for cover, load up, dash back.
That is how I won on hard. 
For the final tear, I hid out in the corner with the vending machines, across from the entrance, and used the sniper rifle, using the same tactic as above.  They will not go into that corner.
I had the hardest time at the graveyard, eventually I hid where the crank gun spawns.  No minions chased me up there, they hung out by the benches in the middle of the yard under the roof.  The lady would attack me every 30 seconds or so.  I got a shot or two on her before she'd leave.  I had to rely on Elizabeth to throw me ammo. I had already emptied all the ammo caches.  Took a while but I had put myself in a bad situation with low ammo and crappy guns.  I believe I had the sniper rifle and a pistol.

Comment: This text is pretty hard to read(long wall of text) would you mind editing so it is easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

Siren is a pain. The only bit I got stuck on in my 1999 mode run so far. On the other difficulties, I could use RTS all day and it over be over like that. In 1999 mode I found I couldn't make that work.

What did work immensely well was destroyng all the undead. The siren has a finite supply, so went there are all gone she cant swarm you.
Shock jockey traps with undertow is insane for this. Drop your trap and power up undertow behind cover nearby. Once it's fully charged, swing out and grab an enemy and pull him right into the trap. Boom- one down. Highly recommend upgrading the undertow to pull 3 enemies and Shock jockey so it arcs between enemies. 
Gear I would suggest would be:
Storm (hat): adds to the killing power of the vigor combo.
Blood to salts (chest): makes the combo essentially free with undertow upgraded. 3 enemies, all with nearly 50% of giving back salts- that's some good work right there.
Urgent care(pants): my personal favourite pants gear. You expose yourself for a few moments, so getting the shield back quickly is VERY important.
Overkill (boots): the only real footwear that is effective for this fight. Can't think of anything else honestly.

Weapons are whatever you are comfortable with. If using overkill, maybe an RPG. I used a shotgun/sniper rifle and hand cannon cause that's what I've been using all run. 
When all the walkers do die, lady Comstock still hits like a TRUCK! Try and keep your distance.

This thread is pretty old, but i just wanted to leave my experience. And to anyone who cant do it... It's do able. You are a trooper and I believe you.